# API Gateway: can I POST to a method/resource with an API key, but by providing the key in the URL params instead of a header?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So, I set up a couple Lambdas and the API gateway. I got it all working! Cool, so then the next step was to require an API key. Ok cool plenty of resources out there on how to set it up.

So I got that working as well and I could POST using postman and python (requests). I can provide the 'x-api-key' in the headers of the POST and it works, no issues.

HOWEVER, and here's the problem: The program I'm going to ultimately be using to POST to my gateway API doesn't allow you to edit the details of your POST. The program is called splunk, [here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjgpq.jpg). Basically it posts some payload for you, the headers/auth/body can't be edited by you, it just sends some pre-configured thing. You just provide the endpoint and it does the rest. This works if I do not require an API key.

So I started thinking, ok no huge problem, I have seen APIs before where you provide the API-Key in the URL and it authenticates you fine. So this would be something like:

*https://exampleAPI/sendmydata?x-api-key=12345*

However, I cannot get this to work in AWS for the life of me. I haven't found anything by googling. Is this something that's even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=764232

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use API key usage plans, you could consider getting the posted API key parameter to API Gateway endpoint A from LambdaA and proxy it with the relevant headers to API Gateway endpoint B.